# JQuery DatePicker to add month to last day of the end month

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use date-picker to do the following: 
When a user select the start date, I need to add 6 months, but the end date should end on the last day of the 5th month.(if that make sense).

I have tried but my code's end date is the first day of the 6th month.

Here my code so far.

```js
$(function() {
$( "#datesix" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                /* Check for the first day */
                if (date.getDate() == 1) { return [true, '']; } 
                else { return [false, '', 'Unavailable']; }
            },onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);
            $("#endsix").datepicker("setDate", date);   
        }
});
      $("#endsix").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                /* Check for the first day */
                if (date.getDate() == 0) { return [true, '']; } 
                else { return [false, '', 'Unavailable']; }
            }    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the 6 months you can exclude one day with

```js
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/nmtyvyc0/